# Samsung SSD is not visible in Bios

Tags: uefi, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspirion N5110 i7 , and I want to upgrade to SSD and I bought Samsung SSD PM810 2.5" 7mm 256MB SSD drive. Everythis is fine, I cloned my system drive successfully on to it, but I can't boot the system from it now.

I also tried to install the drive in the primary drive spot inside laptop, not the ODD. but it still won't boot from SSD. I am clearly seeing the SSD drive in bios info page, but not in the boot priority options.

Also when if I load windows from HHD, and I can use SSD like normal in windows. But it just won't boot from SSD.

I have installed latest bios as well, Do I need to Modify my Bios now ? Could this be anything to do with UEFI ?

Comment: What would happen if you connect that SSD to primary area (not ODD's one)? This is usual I think - SSD for primary and HDD for ODD room.

Comment: you have to try boot only with SSD drive attached, maybe on bios has priority between hdd devices, if boot ok than you have to change that priority, if it doesn't find any drive to boot than the bios doesn't accept the device driver [like old time AHCI and SATA]

Comment: Yeah @emirjonb I have tried that as well. in that case it gives a message boot drive not found or something, don't exactly remember the message.

Comment: How exactly did you clone it? Can you boot the HDD and show Disk Management?

Answer (score -2):

What connection are you using to connect to your SSD?

According to this thread from Dell's forums the Inspiron N5110 will only work with a SATA II or SATA III.

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19471295

It may be the case that Windows software can detect and read the Drive after the OS loads but the BIOS can't detect it on it's own.